# Filtering with Vuejs w/ axios

Tags: vuejs2, axios

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction - I'm fairly new to Vuejs and have taken over someone else's code, although I've managed to do a fair bit without any issues, i'm struggling to get the filtering to work.

Here is the majority of the code:

```js
<template>
<div v-if="showProperties">
            <div v-if="properties.length > 0">

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2 listings--filter">
                        <select v-model="filter" class="form-control listings--filter_select">
                            <option value="" disabled hidden>Filter</option>
                            <option value="price-lowest">Lowest Price First</option>
                            <option value="price-highest">Highest Price First</option>
                            <option value="listing-new">Newest Listing First</option>
                            <option value="listing-old">Oldest Listing First</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                <div class="col-2 listings--filtersstc">
                <toggle-button  v-model="sstcBtn"
                :value="true"
               :labels="{checked: 'Show SSTC', unchecked: 'Hide SSTC'}"
               :width="120"
               :height="40"/>
               </div> 


                </div>

                <div class="row margin-bottom">

                    <div class="col listings--filter">
                        <small v-show="showRemoveFilter">Current filter: {{ selectedFilter }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col listings--filter">
                        <small v-show="showRemoveFilter" v-on:click="removeSortProperties" class="float-right">Remove filter</small>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <property-listings v-for="(property, index) in properties" v-bind:property="property" v-bind:key="index"></property-listings>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div v-else>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <p class="dark-text">No properties match your search criteria. Please try again.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

    import PropertyListings from './PropertyListings.vue'
    import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
    import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'

    Vue.use(ToggleButton)

    Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
      load: {
        key: '-------------------',
        libraries: 'places', // This is required if you use the Autocomplete plugin
        // OR: libraries: 'places,drawing'
        // OR: libraries: 'places,drawing,visualization'
        // (as you require)
      }
    })  

    export default {
       
        data () {
            return {
                showProperties: false,
                properties: [],
                filter: '',
                sstcBtn: true,
                selectedFilter: '',
                showRemoveFilter: false,
                center: {lat: 00000, lng: -000000},
                propertyInfoName: '',
                propertyInfoPrice: '',
                propertyInfoLink: '',
                propertyInfoType: '',
                infoWindowPos: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lng: 0
                },
                infoWinOpen: false,
                currentMidx: null

            }
        },
        delimiters: ['<%', '%>'],
        components: {
            PropertyListings
        },
        watch: {
            filter: function(newFilter, oldFilter) {
                this.sortProperties(newFilter);
            },
            sstcBtn: function(newSstcBtn, oldSstcBtn) {
                this.removeSstcProperties(newSstcBtn);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sortProperties: _.debounce(
                function(newFilter) {

                    if(newFilter === 'price-highest') {

                        this.properties = _.orderBy(this.properties, 'price', 'desc')
                        this.selectedFilter = 'Highest Price First'

                    } else if(newFilter === 'price-lowest') {

                        this.properties = _.orderBy(this.properties, 'price', 'asc')
                        this.selectedFilter = 'Lowest Price First'

                    } else if(newFilter === 'listing-new') {

                        this.properties = _.orderBy(this.properties, 'id', 'desc')
                        this.selectedFilter = 'Newest Listing First'

                    } else if(newFilter === 'listing-old') {

                        this.properties = _.orderBy(this.properties, 'id', 'asc')
                        this.selectedFilter = 'Oldest Listing First'

                    }

                    this.showRemoveFilter = true

                },
                500
            ),
            removeSstcProperties: _.debounce(
                function(newSstcBtn) {
                    if(newSstcBtn == true){
                        console.log('do not filter')
                            //this.properties = _.filterBy(this.properties, 'status_id', '1')
                            return this.properties.filter(function(property){
                                return property.status_id == "1"
                            }.bind(this))

                    } else if(newSstcBtn == false){
                        console.log('do filter')
                    }

                }, 
                500

            ),
            removeSortProperties: function() {

                this.properties = _.orderBy(this.properties, 'id', 'desc')
                this.showRemoveFilter = false

            },

              toggleInfoWindow: function(property, idx) {

                this.infoWindowPos = {lat: Number(property.latitude), lng: Number(property.longitude)}
                this.propertyInfoName = property.display_address
                this.propertyInfoPrice = property.price

                if(property.let_type_id === '3') {
                    this.propertyInfoLink = '/properties/for-students/' + property.main_searchable_areas + '/' + property.slug + '/' + property.property_ref
                } else if(jQuery.inArray(property.let_type_id, ['1','2']) != '-1'){
                    this.propertyInfoLink = '/properties/for-rent/' + property.main_searchable_areas + '/' + property.slug + '/' + property.property_ref
                } else {
                    this.propertyInfoLink = '/properties/for-sale/' + property.main_searchable_areas + '/' + property.slug + '/' + property.property_ref
                }

           
              }

        },
        created() {
            var self = this;
            axios.get('/properties/json')
              .then(function (response) {
                self.properties = response.data
                self.showProperties = true
               
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });

        } 

    }
</script>
```

Everything else is working fine but the bit i've been working on is the removeSstcProperties method, I've got the method triggering fine, however I'm struggling to actually filter the results for properties that have the status_id = 1. I've tried 2 ways (one commented out). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would use it like this `this.properties = this.properties.filter((property) => {
                                return property.status_id == "1"
                            })`

Comment: Ah, I was close! Thank you. I'm just trying to return the properties, so I tried `this.properties = this.properties.filter((property) => { return property.status_id == "0" || property.status_id == "1" }` but that doesn't appear to work. Any idea how to remove the filter? Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why the `or` (`||`) wont work. https://jsfiddle.net/Jubels/eywraw8t/405059/ It works here.